# ¿Como asignarle un escuchas a una JTable?

Tags: java, eventos, interfaz-gráfica, jtable

Tengo un `JTable` con los datos de alumnos (nombre,semestre,especialidad) y necesito hacer que cuando el usuario seleccione una fila de la tabla me imprima los datos de la fila que selecciono. Se me ocurrió agregarle un  `MouseListener` y que este se activara cuando el usuario da clik sobre la fila, pero no se que código poner en el `mouseClicked`.

codigo:

```
public void ecuchas() {
  table.addMouseListener(new Escucha_Mouse());
}

class Escucha_Mouse implements MouseListener{
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo usaría mejor `addListSelectionListener` en lugar de `addMouseListener`.

```
jtable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        String nombre = jtable.getValueAt(jtable.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
        String semestre = jtable.getValueAt(jtable.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString();
        String especialidad = jtable.getValueAt(jtable.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString();
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombre + " | Semestre: " + semestre + " | Especialidad: " + especialidad);
    }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me funciono correctamente